# FCKEditor with KCFinder UserFilesPath

Tags: php, fckeditor, kcfinder

On my web application I use FCKEditor to edit news. The FCKEditor is using KCFinder for browsing the server for files or images.

In the config.php (FCKEditor->connector->browser) I configured the UserFilesPath and the UserFilesAbsolutePath. The UserFilesPath contains the full `http://www.domain.tld/images/files/` path and the UserFilesAbsolutePath contains the same path but with document root instead of the tld.

But when I go to FCKEditor window and try to add a link to a text, first the dialog opens, than I click on Browser Server and when I double click on a file I get back to the dialog box with a path like this: `/images/files/xyz.pdf` (e.g.).

Actually I would need the path like this: `http://www.domain.tld/images/files/xyz.pdf`

Please review the scenario and provide some solution.

Answer (score 0):

StartupPath is a property of the CKFinder object. See [documentation](http://docs.fckeditor.net/CKFinder/Developers_Guide/PHP/Integration) for more information.

There is a working example included in the CKFinder package that shows how StartupPath can be used: "_samples/js/popups.html".

StartupPath can be used in a similar way when CKFinder is attached to FCKeditor with the SetupFCKeditor method.

In javascript you can use also the following syntax:

```
CKFinder.SetupFCKeditor( oFCKeditor, { BasePath : '/ckfinder/', StartupPath :
 'Images:/path/to/directory/' } ) ;
```

So, for a fully working example of setting StartupPath when CKFinder is integrated with FCKeditor, just follow these steps:

- open `_samples/js/fckeditor.html`
- comment out this line `(add double slash - "//"): //CKFinder.SetupFCKeditor( oFCKeditor, '../../' );`
- add the following code one line below:
  `CKFinder.SetupFCKeditor( oFCKeditor, { BasePath : '../../', StartupPath : 'Images:/directory/' } ) ;`
  where `"Images:/directory/"` is a valid startup path and it should work.

Comment: Thank you for your fast reply... but you missed, that I wrote KCFinder and not CKFinder... Do you know about KCFinder to?

Comment: Pardon mate. Do you want `FCKEditor` integrated with `KCFinder`? I have some knowledge of `KCFinder` as well.

Comment: Did you set the permissions to `0777`?

Comment: Yes, I want to pick a file in the browser and get back the http://tld path to the FCKEditors dialog box.

Comment: Please review this link: [KCFinder CKEditor Integration](http://kcfinder.sunhater.com/integrate)

Comment: Thank you, but this integrations guide does not solve my problem... Do you understand what I want to solve?

Comment: I understand what you want to get done But can you please explain what exactly is the problem?

Comment: I want to pick one file in the browser and get back the full qualified domain name in front of the path. At this moment I only get the path like /images/files/xyz.pdf

Comment: OK let me get you useful code to overcome this problem.